# Fix backward array.size() unsigned int

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to print my array backwards. Why does the returning of array.size() - 1 gives the maximum number of unsigned long?

```
int main(){

  array<double, 5> zArray = {};

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < zArray.size(); ++i) {
     cout << "Input "<< i+1 << ". Number: ";
     cin >> zArray.at(i);
  }

  cout << "Backwards" << endl;


  for (unsigned int j = zArray.size() -1; j >= 0; j--) {
     cout << zArray.at(j) << " ";
  }

  cout << endl;
}
```

When i replace the for loop with a normal integer, the the program is working correctly. Why does the unsigned int return the error `std::out_of_range` with the maximum of `4294967295`? The return value of array.size() is a unsigned int or not?

The full error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  array::at: __n (which is 4294967295) >= _Nm (which is 5)`

Comment: because this is `-1` in unsigned int ...

Comment: Is it not just a mathematical subtraction?

Comment: Also note that STL containers `size()` and `sizeof()` functions return `size_t` which is implementation defined. On popular 64-bit platforms, this is defined as `unsigned long` not `unsigned int` hence `std::out_of_range`. It is preferable to leave the data model up to the implementation when using STL.

Comment: To answer something like this, ask yourself again: why wouldn't it? What did you expect instead, and why? Then research each of those assumptions until you find the one that's wrong. It's how we did software development before Stack Overflow ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop can never end. Since `j` is `unsigned`, it will always be greater than or equal to zero. So `j >= 0` will always be true.

Before you subtract from an `unsigned` value, you really need to test to make sure the subtraction won't underflow. And your compiler should have given you a warning that the comparison will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

The array's `size()` method returns an **unsigned** value, so when you loop backwards and reach index 0, the next iteration will set `j` to  `0 - 1`, which wraps around to the largest value of the unsigned type.  This is defined behavior of the language.  So your `>= 0` condition will always be true.

The `std::out_of_range` error is because the array's `at()` method performs bounds checking, and the result of the wrap produces a value that is outside the array's defined bounds, just as the error message says.

You can avoid this by using iterators instead of indexes:

```
int main(){
    array<double, 5> zArray = {};
    std::size_t idx = 0;

    for (auto &d : zArray) {
        cout << "Input " << idx + 1 << ". Number: ";
        cin >> d;
        ++idx;
    }

    cout << "Backwards" << endl;

    for (auto iter = zArray.rbegin(); iter != zArray.rend(); ++iter) {
        cout << *iter << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```